# How do I loop the label variable in python tkinter?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, user-interface, tkinter

I have a loop like below to read the voltage values for different devices.

```
for dut in range(TEST_BENCH_CURRENT_NB_DUTS):
    if dut_sn[dut].get() == "" :               
                 
    for voltage_test in range(Initial_voltages):
        # Delay between voltage readings                   
        try:
            # Read DUT Voltage
            time.sleep(1)
            voltage = swapBits(busI2C.read_word_data(*I2C_ADDRESSES_1[voltage_test])) >> 4 
            voltage_readings[dut][voltage_test].set(str(voltage))
            window.update()
            time.sleep(0.1)                       
        except:
            voltage = 0
            text = voltage_readings[dut][voltage_test].set(VOLTAGE_READ_PB)
            window.update()              
          
        minimum_value = float(LIST_TP_VOLTAGE_MIN[voltage_test][7:])
        maximum_value = float(LIST_TP_VOLTAGE_MAX[voltage_test][7:])

        # Control value is min < value < max
        if voltage < minimum_value or maximum_value < voltage :                        
          #label_DUT1_Global_OK_KO_Status = Entry(window, textvariable=voltage_readings[dut][voltage_test], font=(None,TEXT_SIZE), highlightbackground ='red', state=DISABLED, justify=CENTER, width=ENTRY_WIDTH)
```

And also I have a GUI built with tkinter to display these values.

```
voltage_readings = []
for dut in range(NUM_DUT):
    voltage_readings.append([])
    for voltage_test in range(Initial_voltages):
        voltage_readings[dut].append(StringVar())


label_DUT1_Voltage_Readings_01 = Entry(window, textvariable=voltage_readings[1 - 1][1 - 1], font=(None,TEXT_SIZE), disabledbackground ="#f7f5f5", disabledforeground ="black", state=DISABLED, justify=CENTER, width=ENTRY_WIDTH).place(x=X_LABEL_DUT1-X_LABEL_KEY_PADDING,y=Y_LABEL_FIRST+LIST_SCREEN_ORDER[2]*Y_LABEL_SPACE)
label_DUT2_Voltage_Readings_01 = Entry(window, textvariable=voltage_readings[2 - 1][1 - 1], font=(None,TEXT_SIZE), disabledbackground ="#f7f5f5", disabledforeground ="black", state=DISABLED, justify=CENTER, width=ENTRY_WIDTH).place(x=X_LABEL_DUT2-X_LABEL_KEY_PADDING,y=Y_LABEL_FIRST+LIST_SCREEN_ORDER[2]*Y_LABEL_SPACE)
label_DUT3_Voltage_Readings_01 = Entry(window, textvariable=voltage_readings[3 - 1][1 - 1], font=(None,TEXT_SIZE), disabledbackground ="#f7f5f5", disabledforeground ="black", state=DISABLED, justify=CENTER, width=ENTRY_WIDTH).place(x=X_LABEL_DUT3-X_LABEL_KEY_PADDING,y=Y_LABEL_FIRST+LIST_SCREEN_ORDER[2]*Y_LABEL_SPACE)
label_DUT4_Voltage_Readings_01 = Entry(window, textvariable=voltage_readings[4 - 1][1 - 1], font=(None,TEXT_SIZE), disabledbackground ="#f7f5f5", disabledforeground ="black", state=DISABLED, justify=CENTER, width=ENTRY_WIDTH).place(x=X_LABEL_DUT4-X_LABEL_KEY_PADDING,y=Y_LABEL_FIRST+LIST_SCREEN_ORDER[2]*Y_LABEL_SPACE)    

label_DUT1_Voltage_Readings_02 = Entry(window, textvariable=voltage_readings[1 - 1][2 - 1], font=(None,TEXT_SIZE), disabledbackground ="#f7f5f5", disabledforeground ="black", state=DISABLED, justify=CENTER, width=ENTRY_WIDTH).place(x=X_LABEL_DUT1-X_LABEL_KEY_PADDING,y=Y_LABEL_FIRST+LIST_SCREEN_ORDER[3]*Y_LABEL_SPACE)
label_DUT2_Voltage_Readings_02 = Entry(window, textvariable=voltage_readings[2 - 1][2 - 1], font=(None,TEXT_SIZE), disabledbackground ="#f7f5f5", disabledforeground ="black", state=DISABLED, justify=CENTER, width=ENTRY_WIDTH).place(x=X_LABEL_DUT2-X_LABEL_KEY_PADDING,y=Y_LABEL_FIRST+LIST_SCREEN_ORDER[3]*Y_LABEL_SPACE)
label_DUT3_Voltage_Readings_02 = Entry(window, textvariable=voltage_readings[3 - 1][2 - 1], font=(None,TEXT_SIZE), disabledbackground ="#f7f5f5", disabledforeground ="black", state=DISABLED, justify=CENTER, width=ENTRY_WIDTH).place(x=X_LABEL_DUT3-X_LABEL_KEY_PADDING,y=Y_LABEL_FIRST+LIST_SCREEN_ORDER[3]*Y_LABEL_SPACE)
label_DUT4_Voltage_Readings_02 = Entry(window, textvariable=voltage_readings[4 - 1][2 - 1], font=(None,TEXT_SIZE), disabledbackground ="#f7f5f5", disabledforeground ="black", state=DISABLED, justify=CENTER, width=ENTRY_WIDTH).place(x=X_LABEL_DUT4-X_LABEL_KEY_PADDING,y=Y_LABEL_FIRST+LIST_SCREEN_ORDER[3]*Y_LABEL_SPACE)    

label_DUT1_Voltage_Readings_03 = Entry(window, textvariable=voltage_readings[1 - 1][3 - 1], font=(None,TEXT_SIZE), disabledbackground ="#f7f5f5", disabledforeground ="black", state=DISABLED, justify=CENTER, width=ENTRY_WIDTH).place(x=X_LABEL_DUT1-X_LABEL_KEY_PADDING,y=Y_LABEL_FIRST+LIST_SCREEN_ORDER[4]*Y_LABEL_SPACE)
label_DUT2_Voltage_Readings_03 = Entry(window, textvariable=voltage_readings[2 - 1][3 - 1], font=(None,TEXT_SIZE), disabledbackground ="#f7f5f5", disabledforeground ="black", state=DISABLED, justify=CENTER, width=ENTRY_WIDTH).place(x=X_LABEL_DUT2-X_LABEL_KEY_PADDING,y=Y_LABEL_FIRST+LIST_SCREEN_ORDER[4]*Y_LABEL_SPACE)
label_DUT3_Voltage_Readings_03 = Entry(window, textvariable=voltage_readings[3 - 1][3 - 1], font=(None,TEXT_SIZE), disabledbackground ="#f7f5f5", disabledforeground ="black", state=DISABLED, justify=CENTER, width=ENTRY_WIDTH).place(x=X_LABEL_DUT3-X_LABEL_KEY_PADDING,y=Y_LABEL_FIRST+LIST_SCREEN_ORDER[4]*Y_LABEL_SPACE)
label_DUT4_Voltage_Readings_03 = Entry(window, textvariable=voltage_readings[4 - 1][3 - 1], font=(None,TEXT_SIZE), disabledbackground ="#f7f5f5", disabledforeground ="black", state=DISABLED, justify=CENTER, width=ENTRY_WIDTH).place(x=X_LABEL_DUT4-X_LABEL_KEY_PADDING,y=Y_LABEL_FIRST+LIST_SCREEN_ORDER[4]*Y_LABEL_SPACE)
```

SO, my problem is when the voltage value is out of the bounds I need to highlight a particular label In red.
Can someone please help me how to loop these label variables to do so.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide us a Minimal Working Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that we can run? Just a single entry and any required function would do the work. No need to provide us extra code.

Comment: `label_DUT1_Voltage_Readings_01` and so on are all `None`, the result of calling `.place()` on the actual widgets - and are therefore completely useless.  If you need a reference to the widget (so that you can change its color, for example), you have to do the geometry management as a separate statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in tkinter for labals name `configure()` method. I m going to give u an example to understand more :

```
global x
x=0
lbl=Label(root,text=x)
lbl.pack()
for I in range [0,20] :
    sleep(1)
    lbl.configure(text=str(x+1))
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use `sleep` with `tkinter` as it freezes the app

Comment: Thank you Rayen, Does it work the same for  lbl=Entry(root,text=x) instead of label?